# Using the CBOR format instead of JSON in elasticsearch ingest plugin

Tags: elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin, elk, cbor

In the documentation of Ingest Attachment Processor Plugin in Elasticsearch, it is mentioned, "If you do not want to incur the overhead of converting back and forth between base64, you can use the CBOR format instead of JSON and specify the field as a bytes array instead of a string representation. The processor will skip the base64 decoding then." Could anyone please throw some light on this or maybe share an example of how to achieve this? I need to index a very large number of documents having a significant size. So I need to minimise the latency.